# Сделать парсер температуры

Tags: python, парсер

Есть скрипт, который снимает значение температуры с датчика и выводит на экран, проблема в том что нужно чтобы цикл запускался по задействованию скрипта и был не бесконечный, и чтобы регулярными выражениями снималась только одна строка со значением температуры.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
def page(url):
    '''
    Читает исходник из переданного аргумента(адреса)
    '''
    return urlopen(url).read() # Вернуть исходник
def printer():
    '''
    Выводит весь исходный код в командную строку
    '''
    print(get_url)
def record_file():
    '''
    Записывает исходник в файл
    '''

l_demo = [] # Создать пустой словарь
while 1: 
    try: 
        my_int = "http://192.168.1.1/public"

        just = my_int # Запомнить введенный адрес в переменной just
        l_demo.append(my_int) # Добавить его в словарь
        print(l_demo, "Минутку...") # Вывести содержимое словаря и сообщение
        if l_demo[0][:7] == 'http://': # Если протокол введен...
            get_url = page(l_demo[0]) # Передать адрес функции page() и создать объект функции
            print("Все верно!!!!!!!") 
        else:
            fixed = "http://" + l_demo[0] # Если не введен, добавить путем создания новой переменной 
            get_url = page(fixed) # Так же передать адрес функции page()
            print("Ага!..")
        l_demo.remove(my_int) # Удалить адрес из словаря
    except: # Адрес введен неверно
        print("Адрес не действителен! Проверьте правильность ввода")
        l_demo.remove(my_int)
        continue

    rec_out = "R"; ("Записать исходник в файл или вывести тут? \nВведите для выбора: R/O")
    if rec_out == 'R':
            printer()
    else:
        record_file()
```

*С Python не знаком, поэтому прошу помощи.*

Comment: А какой там у вас формат данных мы будет угадывать, да? :)

Comment: *Запомнить введенный адрес в переменной just* — нет, в Python это не так. *== 'http://':* — боже, *import urlparse* или варианты в зависимости от версии интерпретатора.

Comment: формат Html , нужно просто значение температуры принтом выводить в скрипт что бы его потом забикс подхватывал.

Comment: дайте пример входных данных. Иначе вам ни кто не поможет.